# Ajuda em react, como faço para aparecer somente os itens em estoque?

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho o seguinte problema, criar um array onde mostre uma lista com eles e um botão para mostrar somente os que estão em estoque("sim").

Quero fazer com que quando eu clique no botão apareça os itens que no nome estoque esteja "sim", mas não sei ao certo oque deveria mudar.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function formatarPreco(valor) {
  return valor.toLocaleString(undefined, {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "BRL"
  });
}

export default function App() {
  const [produtos, setProdutos] = useState([]);
  const lista = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: "Livro",
      preco: 32.99,
      estoque: "sim"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nome: "Tenis",
      preco: 132.99,
      estoque: "sim"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      nome: "Monitor",
      preco: 689.99,
      estoque: "nao"
    }
  ];

  const disponiveis = (produto) => {
    const contemProduto = lista.estoque === "sim";
    if (!contemProduto) {
      <div> {lista.nome}: Indisponível </div>;
    } else {
      <div>
        Produto: {lista.nome} disponível <br /> Valor: {lista.preco}
      </div>;
    }
    setProdutos(contemProduto);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Produtos em Estoque</h1>
      <ul id="list">
        {lista.map((produto) => (
          <div className="conteudo">
            Nome: {produto.nome} - Preço: {formatarPreco(produto.preco)}
            <div className="informacoes">
              <button onClick={() => disponiveis(produto)}>
                Verificar Status
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        ;
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Não entendi ao certo o que você quis dizer, sua pergunta não está muito clara, mas creio que você queira carregar apenas os items em estoque (`estoque: "sim"`). O que você pode fazer é colocar uma verificação para saber se o item está disponível ou não quando for renderiza-los.

```
<ul id="list">
    {lista.map((produto) => ( produto.estoque === "sim" ?
      <div className="conteudo">
        Nome: {produto.nome} - Preço: {formatarPreco(produto.preco)}
        <div className="informacoes">
          <button onClick={() => disponiveis(produto)}>
            Verificar Status
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      : <div/>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Recomendação de leitura: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: É isso que quero fazer, só não sei ao certo se está no rumo

Comment: Você poderia estar atualizando a pergunta com mais detalhes para saber melhor o que você precisa, ou caso se a resposta respondeu sua pergunta marcar como aceita.